# What's CQL 'PRIMARY KEY ((k1), k2, k3)' mean?

Tags: cassandra, primary-key, cql

In CQL code I'm maintaining (author not available), I find a Cassandra table declaration that says, in part

```
PRIMARY KEY ((k1), k2, k3)
```

Do those inner parens mean anything in this case? Or is it merely redundant?

To clarify:

1. I know what `PRIMARY KEY (k1, k2, k3)` would mean (partition on k1, cluster on k2 and k3).
2. I know what `PRIMARY KEY ((k1, k2), k3)` would mean (partition on (k1, k2), cluster on k3)
3. But is the cited code just equivalent to #1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `PRIMARY KEY ((k1), k2, k3)` is basically the same as `PRIMARY KEY (k1, k2, k3)`.  In the case of designating a single partition key, you can opt to *not* specify the partition parens.  They are really only necessary if you are creating a composite partition key (like you are with your point #2).